# What are some synonyms for 'seat' in a political context?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

What are some synonyms for 'seat' in a political context? For example, if you describe the results of an election, it doesn't sound good when you repeatedly say 'party A won X seats, party B won Y seats, etc.' I would like to hear some alternatives. I believe I've already asked this question somewhere, but I haven't found it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just that sentence, you can just omit the second 'seats':

> The Democrats won 100 seats, and the Republicans 50.

is perfectly understandable. An alternative would be to talk about *people* instead of seats, i.e.

> Party A won X seats, while Y candidates from party B were elected.

Comment: You can use it once with a list. The Red Party won 100 seats, the Blue 50, the Green 65, the Yellow 14. Note I only used Party once also, but repeated 'the'.